# Reference request for "the Buddha takes the Dhamma as his superior"

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon

In what Pali sutta[s] does the Buddha says something approximately like,

> Everyone needs someone better than them, who they can revere and who can guide them: who will be their teacher. But there is no-one better than the Buddha: and so I take the Dhamma as my guide/superior/teacher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Garava Sutta (SN 6.2)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn06/sn06.002.than.html):

> I have heard that on one occasion, when the Blessed One was newly
>   Self-awakened, he was staying at Uruvela on the bank of the Nerañjara
>   River, at the foot of the Goatherd's Banyan Tree. Then, while he was
>   alone and in seclusion, this line of thinking arose in his awareness:
>   "One suffers if dwelling without reverence or deference. Now on what
>   brahman or contemplative can I dwell in dependence, honoring and
>   respecting him?"
>
> Then the thought occurred to him: "It would be for the sake of
>   perfecting an unperfected aggregate of virtue that I would dwell in
>   dependence on another brahman or contemplative, honoring and
>   respecting him. However, in this world with its devas, Maras, &
>   Brahmas, in this generation with its brahmans and contemplatives, its
>   royalty and common-folk, **I do not see another brahman or contemplative
>   more consummate in virtue than I, on whom I could dwell in dependence,
>   honoring and respecting him.**
>
> "It would be for the sake of perfecting an unperfected aggregate of
>   concentration that I would dwell in dependence on another brahman or
>   contemplative, honoring and respecting him. However, in this world
>   with its devas, Maras, & Brahmas, in this generation with its brahmans
>   and contemplatives, its royalty and common-folk, **I do not see another
>   brahman or contemplative more consummate in concentration than I, on
>   whom I could dwell in dependence, honoring and respecting him.**
>
> "It would be for the sake of perfecting an unperfected aggregate of
>   discernment that I would dwell in dependence on another brahman or
>   contemplative, honoring and respecting him. However, in this world
>   with its devas, Maras, & Brahmas, in this generation with its brahmans
>   and contemplatives, its royalty and common-folk, **I do not see another
>   brahman or contemplative more consummate in discernment than I, on
>   whom I could dwell in dependence, honoring and respecting him.**
>
> "It would be for the sake of perfecting an unperfected aggregate of
>   release that I would dwell in dependence on another brahman or
>   contemplative, honoring and respecting him. However, in this world
>   with its devas, Maras, & Brahmas, in this generation with its brahmans
>   and contemplatives, its royalty and common-folk, **I do not see another
>   brahman or contemplative more consummate in release than I, on whom I
>   could dwell in dependence, honoring and respecting him.**
>
> "It would be for the sake of perfecting an unperfected aggregate of
>   knowledge and vision of release that I would dwell in dependence on
>   another brahman or contemplative, honoring and respecting him.
>   However, in this world with its devas, Maras, & Brahmas, in this
>   generation with its brahmans and contemplatives, its royalty and
>   common-folk, **I do not see another brahman or contemplative more
>   consummate in knowledge and vision of release than I, on whom I could
>   dwell in dependence, honoring and respecting him.**
>
> **"What if I were to dwell in dependence on this very Dhamma to which I
>   have fully awakened, honoring and respecting it?"**
>
> Then, having known with his own awareness the line of thinking in the
>   Blessed One's awareness — just as a strong man might extend his flexed
>   arm or flex his extended arm — Brahma Sahampati disappeared from the
>   Brahma-world and reappeared in front of the Blessed One. Arranging his
>   upper robe over one shoulder, he saluted the Blessed One with his
>   hands before his heart and said to him: "So it is, Blessed One! So it
>   is, One-Well-Gone! **Those who were Arahants, Rightly Self-awakened Ones
>   in the past — they, too, dwelled in dependence on the very Dhamma
>   itself, honoring and respecting it. Those who will be Arahants,
>   Rightly Self-awakened Ones in the future — they, too, will dwell in
>   dependence on the very Dhamma itself, honoring and respecting it. And
>   let the Blessed One, who is at present the Arahant, the Rightly
>   Self-awakened One, dwell in dependence on the very Dhamma itself,
>   honoring and respecting it."**
>
> That is what Brahma Sahampati said. Having said that, he further said
>   this:
>
> Past Buddhas,
>   future Buddhas,
>   & he who is the Buddha now,
>   removing the sorrow of many —
>
> all have dwelt,
>   will dwell, he dwells,
>   **revering the true Dhamma.**
>   This, for Buddhas, is a natural law.
>
> Therefore one who desires his own good,
>   aspiring for greatness,
>   should respect the true Dhamma,
>   recollecting the Buddhas' Teaching.

Comment: Thank you. I think there's one (earlier in his life) where the Buddha said that he himself venerates (or something like that) the Dhamma -- takes it as *his* teacher (or guide or refuge or I don't quite remember what).

Comment: If you find this I'd be very interested as the Buddha is one who has no more learning to do. If he said thus, I imagine he was speaking in the past tense of when he was a Bodhisat.

Comment: @YesheTenley I don't think it was "learning" -- I think it was more something like "staying within the guidelines of", perhaps even venerating -- "teacher" meaning in the sense of "master"; or perhaps benefactor... I think the sutta I'm talking of exists, I find it difficult to search for though, and I'd like to read again more carefully how it's worded. I remember it as present tense and after his enlightenment.

Comment: I found it! It's the Garava Sutta (SN 6.2). Now updated in the answer. I have also removed the others which you aren't looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but there is [this Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/an3.26/en/bodhi) where the Buddha instructs that people should associate with those superior to them (AN 3.26):

> “Bhikkhus, there are these three kinds of persons found existing in
>   the world. What three? (1) There is a person who is not to be
>   associated with, followed, and served; (2) a person who is to be
>   associated with, followed, and served; and (3) a person who is to be
>   associated with, followed, and served with honor and respect.
>
> ...
>
> “These, bhikkhus, are the three kinds of persons found existing in the
>   world.”
>
> One who associates with an inferior person declines; one who
>   associates with an equal does not decline; attending on a superior
>   person one develops quickly; therefore you should follow one superior
>   to yourself.

Regarding the relationship between the Buddha and Dhamma [there is also this:](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.087x.wlsh.html)

> "Enough, Vakkali! What is there to see in this vile body? He who sees
>   Dhamma, Vakkali, sees me; he who sees me sees Dhamma. Truly seeing
>   Dhamma, one sees me; seeing me one sees Dhamma."

I think the Buddha was exhorting such out of great compassion for he said this to a dying man who was expressing regret.

Comment: Thank you, yes; but that is missing the second part, about the Buddha's taking the Dhamma as his own, to be his own ... his own "something".