# can meditation and dharma alone take us to higher levels of consciousness?

Tags: meditation, dharmas

I have been practising dharma and meditation now for more than 2 years and i feel a good progress within me. Does these 2 tools dharma and meditation alone can take us through to different levels of consciousness ?

Comment: If by dharma you mean the Buddhist teachings then I'd suggest that just meditation is enough, since the teachings arise from meditation.

Comment: i feel dhamma is common phenomenon in this spiritual process. Astanga Yoga says about dhamma in the terms of iyama and niyama. I come from Tamil language where tirukural literature talks about dhamma in the terms of aram. i strive to walk in the path of dhamma always.

Comment: @SGN:: clarify what u mean by *dharma* in question? Is it dharma or `dhamma` u r asking for as you strive to walk on dhamma?

Answer (score 1):

The Dharma alone is the true medicine and it alone can cure us of the unsatisfactoriness of samsara. The Buddhas and Sangha are like the best doctors and nurses in the world and can help guide us in the best way to take the medicine - the Dharma - but it is the medicine alone which actually heals!

Theoretically, if we just take the medicine at the right time, in the right way, in the right amount... we do not need doctors and nurses... the medicine is enough.

Practically, we almost always need good doctors and nurses to help us prescribe and apply the medicine and thus we need to take refuge in the Buddhas and Sangha as well.

This is how it has been explained to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Dhamma**:: Right Teachings

Meditation:: Tool to establish in dhamma

Different levels of Consciousness:: Comes when one uses tool to establish in dhamma.

Other tools:: Enable one to be able to use `Meditation` tool.

Answer (score 0):

There's doctrine which says that a good friend (perhaps "exemplar") is important too: for example [SN 45.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.2/en/sujato).

Apparently the Buddha, having no-one to take as a role-model, used the Dhamma -- [Reference request for "the Buddha takes the Dhamma as his superior"](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/28691/254)